# Can I use XDocument.Save and exclude the XML Declaration?

Tags: .net, xml, linq-to-xml

I'm loading a XML file into a XDocument, doing stuff to it, and calling Save(fileName) to rewrite the XML file. The original file has no XML declaration, is there anyway to avoid XDocument adding a XML declaration?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16681240/how-to-prevent-xdocument-from-adding-xml-version-and-encoding-information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you'll have to use an XmlWriter. Or ToString.

Just found [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387027.aspx) which seems to agree.